# Change Fragment on tab change in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-design

I have three tab A,B,C and fragment from A=>a1,a2,a3, from B=>b1,b2,b3 and same in C. i want when i have change the tab always first fragment are visible like in A=>a1, B=>b1 and C=>c1. but when i have change tab last visit fragment are visible.plz help me.

I am using Tablayout and ViewPager

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: improved  formatting